# Cannot use a global variable in php

Tags: php, laravel-10

I have this function in a controller in laravel 10

```
public function change($id)
{

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        $current_period=Period::where('current',true)->first();
        $current_period->current=false;
        $current_period->save();
        $new_period=Period::findOrFail($id);
        $new_period->current=true;
        $new_period->save();

        //set person's memberSince and pay_mode to what is in the person_period pivot table
        $persons=Person::all();
        $persons->each(function ($person,$key){
            global $new_period;
            //dd($new_period->id);
            $pivot=$person->periods()->where('period_id',$new_period->id)->first();
            $person->memberSince=$pivot? $pivot['memberSince']:null;
            $person->pay_mode=$pivot?$pivot['pay_mode']:null;
            $$person->save();
        });
        DB::commit();
        $result=[];
        $ps=PersonResource::collection(Person::all());
        array_push($result, $ps);
        $pr=PeriodResource::collection(all());
        array_push($result,$pr);
        return $result;

    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

it returns an error

> message   'Attempt to read property "id" on null'

on the line just behind the presently commented line

```
//dd($new_period->id)
```

when I uncomment the line it returns the same error.
When I place the uncommented line outside the each loop, it returns the correct id of `$new_period` confirming that outside the each loop the `$new_period` exists.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try and change your code to `$persons->each(function ($person,$key) use ($new_period) {` and remove the `global $new_period;` and see if it works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `use()` in your closure to expose outer variable. In this case: `use ($new_period)`:

```php
$persons->each(function ($person,$key) use ($new_period) {
    $pivot=$person->periods()->where('period_id',$new_period->id)->first();
    // the rest of your handler...
});
```

Check the [3rd example in this PHP documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 1):

PHP's anonymous functions require you to explicitly state which variables it has access to. As you're not doing that, `$new_period` is not defined in the `->each()` callback. You can solve this using the `use`-keyword as follows:

```php
$persons->each(function ($person, $key) use ($new_period) {
    // Your existing code
});
```

See also example #3 from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).